# How do I return a value after promise is resolved Angular Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am using Angular and Typescript to make an validation when i insert a value into a SQL database it check if the value is already in the database table. I get a response from an ASP .NET CORE API, if the value is already in the table database server will return **true**.

The response is just this:

```
true
```

For example,i already have value "1" in database table then i am trying to insert value "1" but it will insert it into the table, when i try again to insert the value it will stop and will not let me insert it. If i refresh the page the same process happen even if there are >10 values of "1" in the database table. What can i use to fix this issue and how?

```
FileCount:boolean;
```

```
getFileCount() {
        this.http.get<boolean>(this.BaseURL + '/Count/File?Name=' + this.formData.Name)
        .subscribe(
            result => {
                 this.FileCount = result;
                 console.log(this.FileCount);
            }
        );
    }
```

```
insertRecord(form: NgForm) {
    this.getFileCount();
        if (this.FileCount == true) {
            this.toastr.warning('Submitted failed', 'There is another file with the name: "' + this.formData.Name + '"');
        }
        else {
            this.postFile().subscribe(
                res => {
                    this.toastr.success('Submitted successfully', 'File Creation Complete');
                    this.refreshList();
                },
                (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

```
postFile() {
        return this.http.post(this.BaseURL + '/File', this.formData);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because the call to the this.getFileCount () method runs asynchronously, that is, it does not wait for an answer and the process continues, so you must wait for its response.

Try this:

```
  getFileCount() {
    return this.http.get<boolean>(this.BaseURL + '/Count/File?Name=' + this.formData.Name);
  }

  insertRecord(form: NgForm) {
    this.getFileCount().subscribe(result => {
      this.FileCount = result;
      console.log(this.FileCount);

      if (this.FileCount == true) {
        this.toastr.warning('Submitted failed', 'There is another file with the name: "' + this.formData.Name + '"');
      }
      else {
        this.postFile().subscribe(
          res => {
            this.toastr.success('Submitted successfully', 'File Creation Complete');
            this.refreshList();
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment:  `getFileCount` don't return an observable this will not work ,can you check your answer ?

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmavi Your solution is exactly the same as mine, it is copy and paste. Check your solution. getFileCount does return an observable.

Comment: at the first you was try to solve this by using async await ,that why I menthion another way 

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmavi No, I proposed 2 solutions, Eduard worked the 2nd. That's why I deleted the other one, but I'm sure it worked.

Comment: maybe I don't see that don't worry I will remove mine , we don't need to confuse other people when the try to solve their problem in future 